# Unable to fill temp table with numbers in Amazon Redshift, row count is less than expected

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

The goal is to create a temp table with numbers from 1 to 25567.
I tried this SQL statements:

```
-- Create temp table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS numbers;

CREATE TEMP TABLE numbers 
(
    n INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Insert numbers from 1 to 25567
INSERT INTO numbers
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS n
    FROM stl_scan
    LIMIT 25567;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers

3632
```

Why are there less rows than expected? and instead of starting at 1, the first row is 4, and goes on by 4 (8, 12, 16, and so on)

Comment: What appears if you just run the SELECT?

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY cans lead to unconsistent values because of cache or parallelism execution of query. In this case, parallelism has certainluy be used with 4 threads...

Comment: @JohnRotenstein If I just run the SELECT it works fine

Comment: @SQLpro ORDER BY didn't do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO numbers
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS n
    FROM stl_scan
    ORDER BY n OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH 25567 ROWS ONLY;
```

This is real ISO standard SQL. LIMIT does not exists in pure SQL and is the most stupid functionality like TOP in some other RDBMS !

Comment: ROW FETCH throws an error in Redshift, "Unexpected input encountered: 'ROW'. Expecting one of end of file"

Comment: did you try ROWS (both spellings are valid). You can also try ORDER BY n  LIMIT...

Comment: I solved it by uploading a csv file to S3 with the desired numbers and performing a COPY command to the Redshift table. I needed them to properly populate a date dimension.